# Python if conditional statement flow?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I am trying to figure out how to work around this problem. Lets say I have a few if statements and an else statement. It appears when I make a selection that falls under the if, the else statement is also run too. For example:

```
option = float(input("Select Option"))

if (option == 1):
    print("Population Group 1")

if (option == 2):
    print("Population Group 2")

else:
    print("Invalid Selection")

print("Testing")
```

A sample output would be:

```
Select Option1
Population Group 1
Invalid Selection
Testing
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

The `else` statement only pertains to the last `if`. To chain both `if`s to the `else`, use an `if/elif/.../else` sequence:

```
if option == 1:
    print("Population Group 1")

elif option == 2:
    print("Population Group 2")

else:
    print("Invalid Selection")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second `if` statement to an `elif` statement.

Your control flow for `option == 1` goes like this:

```
check first IF statement -> True (no ELSE block to skip)

check second IF statement -> False, continue to ELSE block

execute ELSE block
```

What you wanted:

```
check first IF statement -> True, skip ELSE block
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that only the first **true** condition is matched and avoid the cascade effect, use **elif**:

```
option = float(input("Select Option"))

if option == 1:
   print("Population Group 1")

elif option == 2:
   print("Population Group 2")

else:
   print("Invalid Selection")
print("Testing")
```

Comment: This is a SyntaxError, you applied `elif` a little too liberally there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [python documentation on control flow tools](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html). You simply need to replace the second `if` by a `elif`:

```
option = float(input("Select Option"))

if (option == 1):
    print("Population Group 1")

elif (option == 2):
    print("Population Group 2")

else:
    print("Invalid Selection")

print("Testing")
```